# HerokuにおけるJavaサーバ（Tomcat）上のクラスファイルについて

Tags: java, heroku, tomcat

[Create a Java Web Application using Embedded Tomcat](https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-embedded-tomcat) を利用してJavaによるWebアプリ開発をしたいと思っております。

まず、自分で作ったクラスをindex.jspにインポートして使う、ということをしたいのですが、
例えばTestというクラスをつくり、Test.javaというファイルをindex.jspと同じディレクトリにおいたのですが、index.jspを開くと、

「Test cannot be resolved to a type」と出てきます。`<%@page import="Test"%>`と一応宣言もしています。

```
An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Tes cannot be resolved to a type
4: 
5: <%
6: 
7: Test t = new Test();
```

mvn --versionを叩いたところ、

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (XXXX; 2013-02-19 22:51:28+0900)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: ja_JP, platform encoding: SJIS
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

大まかな質問として、

1. classのファイルはどこにおけばよいか
2. servletのように.javaファイルをコンパイルしなければならないか
3. classの側ではやはりpackageなどの宣言をしなければならないか

その他、上記に対するご指摘など、みなさまのご教授、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すみません、ここに書くための例えでTestとしておりましたが、実際使っているのはTesという名前です。
ここに書く際に同一化を忘れていました。

書き込みありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

ビルド環境などを含めて開発環境に何をお使いなのかが不明瞭なので、明確な答えにならないかもしれません。

使おうとされているembeddedTomcatSampleは、mavenプロジェクトになっておりましたので、私の場合は開発環境としてEclipse4.5.1を選び、Eclipseにてmavenプロジェクトとしてインポートしました。

Eclipseではmavenの自動ビルドを行いますので、アプリケーションのビルドや開発中のコンパイルなどは自動的に行われ、特に意識することもなく、またclassファイルの配置先なども気にする必要はありませんでした。

手順としては、以下のとおりです。

- embededdedTomcatSampleをmavenプロジェクトとしてインポートする
- src/main/java を開き、Main.javaを実行する
- embeddedTomcatがポート8080で実行されるので、http://localhost:8080/ でアクセスする

また、JSPからクラス参照できないとのことでしたが、おそらくJavaクラスがコンパイルされていないか、正しく配置されていないかでしょうか。

私の方で検証用に別パッケージのクラスを作り、Servlet→JSPへのフォワードから読み込むこともできました。

参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 書き込みありがとうございます。
私はJSPなどのファイルを直接VIMで編集しております。
編集の後、xx/src/main/webapp/..のxxにうつり、mvn clean installをかけて、その後foreman start webで5000番ポートのサーバを起動し、ブラウザ上で確認を行っている、といった状況です。

一度IDEを用いる方法をとってみたいと思います。